# Better way to design database table for color+number for uniqueness?

Tags: database-design

I need to design a "Tag" table where some values will be unique on their own (e.g. 123456), but where some will be a combination of the tag color plus a number (e.g. Red 1234).

I could do it like the below and, if TagColor is not null then factor that into the logic, but this way just doesn't feel right.  Any other thoughts how I might design this better?

```
TagId  TagNumber   TagColor
(guid)  123456      (null)
(guid)  234567      (null)
(guid)  ABC123      (null)
(guid)  1234        Red
(guid)  2345        Blue
(guid)  2345        Green
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`TagNumber` and `TagColor` are separate properties and should be defined as such. Together, they make a unique tuple. You would then have a composite index on (`TagNumber`, `TagColor`). What's the point of the surrogate key?

Comment: But some numbers won't have colors to combine with, they will be unique without the color property.  And the reason for the GUID ID is that we do that for ALL tables... an arbitrary unique value that identifies the RECORD.  I believe very strongly in that.  Having as GUID allows for object creation before database insert and also is better for replication.